# Do '不很 + adj' and '很不 + adj' have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning

I have two sentences. **Does 不 preceding or following 很 affect the sentence meaning?**

> ```
> 她不很聪明，但很努力。
> 她很不聪明，但很努力。
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

很不 reinforces the (negated) adjective. 不很 indicates that the subject is "not really" as the adjectives says.

- 很不聪明 - very unintelligent.
- 不很聪明 - not too intelligent, not really intelligent.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add another thing is that: we rarely say 不很 in Chinese. Usually, we say 不是很.

她不是很聪明，但很努力。 -> She is not very smart but she works hard.

Comment: Do you have any internet sources that I can investigate more?

Answer (score 1):

The degree of "不聪明" changes according to the order of words; the object being qualified changes.

```
她不很聪明 ->
她(不(很聪明)) ->
She is not very smart. ->
She might be just ordinary.

她很不聪明 ->
她(很(不聪明)) ->
She is not smart greatly. ->
She might be quite clumsy.
```

Comment: I'm confused that your answer differs from Musialmi's. He says: 
很不聪明 - very unintelligent.
不很聪明 - not too intelligent, not really intelligent.

Comment: @Jenny Hmm? It seems coincident to me. 很不聪明 - very unintelligent - quite clumsy. 不很聪明 - not too intelligent, not really intelligent - ordinary.

Comment: My brain got a bit clumsy because I had thought that very unintelligent = ordinary...